# Fresh Magento Install, Broken Admin [NOT CSS?]

Tags: php, xampp, magento2

I just finished installing Magento in XAMPP. Once I logged in it looks like this:
[Magento Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GylnG.png)
I have tried reinstalling both XAMPP and Magento, but I got the same results.

I have searched for this issue, but the only threads I found were referenced a complete lack of .css which doesn't appear to be the issue for me- though, I am a greenhorn and may not be using the appropriate syntax to search for my issue.

Any idea what my issue is? or even just a solid shove in the correct direction?

Comment: If you right click, inspect element then view the console what do you see? My guess is for some reason a js, or css, file is being improperly called. This could be because your magento url is wrong or it's on HTTPS but your mage url is set to HTTP

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
Several of these specificallyl saying that they refused to apply style from the .CSS because its MIME type is not supported and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Also, refused to execute script errors for the same reason.
Plus, uncaught TypeError require.config is not a function.

Comment: So it seems you have bigger issues. Try loosening your strict MIME typing and/or disable things like adblockers that might be preventing the execution of scripts. Unfortunately, from here on out it's kinda guess and check.

Comment: ok. thanks for the help.